# CSS Button does not display inline for Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

My search button that appears out of place for Mozilla Firefox and I am not sure why it is doing that. 
I am using Bootstrap 4 with Angular 2

Here is what it looks like on Chrome

[image: chrome]

And here is what it looks like on Firefox. The search button does not seem to be inline with the Search Text

[image: firefox]

My HTML Code

```
<button class="btn custom-search-button d-inline" [disabled]="!searchForm.valid">
  Search
  <i class="fa fa-search float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

My CSS Code

```
.custom-search-button {
    color: #A09474;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    border: solid #A09474 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.custom-search-button i {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: try add box-sizing: border-box to .custom-search-button class

Comment: Looks fine to me. does this look ok in firefox? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWwdwK

Comment: Thanks Michael. It does look fine! So it myst be somewhere else in my code that is messing up the styling. Cheers.

Comment: @MichaelCoker that's because you don't have bootstrap linked in.

Comment: Try floating the `<i>` left with CSS. `i {float:left;}` if that doesn't work give it a width and float left.

Comment: @lamelemon nice yep that's it. +1

Comment: @MichaelCoker, do you know why the solution below fixed my problem even though your codepen demonstrated that float-right is OK to be there?

Comment: @user172902 yeah, I didn't include bootstrap in my codepen, just the html and css from the post. my bad, I forgot to include it after reading that you're using it in your post.

Comment: Greatly appreciated. Problem solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `.float-right` from your icon. It's unnecessary and causes the issue.

Comment: This fixed my issue!!! Cheers. How come @MichaelCoker 's codepen worked for both firefox and chrome though? He didnt remove the float-right